# How to know to parameterize time stamps using jmeter?

Tags: date, jmeter, timestamp

We have following type of timestamps used as our post request:

2020-12-11T14:21:52.26

How to parameterize it using jmeter? Which format is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the  **time** function to generate the required time stamps dynamically.

Example :

```
${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,)}
```

Review following documentation to get various date/time formats.

[Time stamp function documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)

[Simple date format documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I tried this but it passes 2020-12-27T10:50:47  instead of 2020-12-27T10:50:47.26   The las t".26" is extra

Comment: @Test Use ${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS,)} Use .SSS at the end to get Milliseconds. Use just .S if you don't need padding.